How to calculate the variance of this random variable?
$\theta$ is a random variable whose distribution is a normal distribution with mean $m_0$ and variance $\sigma_0^2$. Let $u$ be a $k\times1$ random vector following a normal distribution where the mean of every entry is 0 and the covariance matrix is $\Sigma$. Assume $\theta$ and $u_i$ are independent, for $i=1, \cdots, k$. Denote by $e$ by a $k\times 1$ matrix whose elements are all 1. I would like to calculate the variance of this random variable: $e^T\Sigma^{-1}\left(e\theta+u\right)$.
Suppose $A$ is a constant matrix and $x, y$ are random matrix, as long as I know the expression of $Cov(Ax)$ and $Cov(x+y)$, I should be able to derive the result by myself. Could you please tell me what source from which I can know these expressions?

$Var(Ax) = A Var(x) A^{\prime}$

For a constant $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and random $X \in \mathbb{R}^m$
$$\text{var}\left[ AX \right] \equiv \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( AX - \mathbb{E}\left[ AX \right] \right) \left( AX - \mathbb{E}\left[ AX \right] \right)^\top \right] = A \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( X - \mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] \right) \left( X - \mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] \right)^\top \right] = A \text{var}\left[ X \right] A^\top$$
In your case, this means
$$\text{var}\left[ e^\top \Sigma^{-1} \left( e \theta + u \right) \right] = e^\top \Sigma^{-1} \text{var}\left[ e \theta + u \right] \Sigma^{-1} e$$
where
$$u \perp \theta \implies \text{var}\left[ e \theta + u \right] = \text{var}\left[ e \theta \right] + \text{var}\left[ u \right] = \sigma_0^2 e e^\top + \Sigma$$
Putting it all together we get
$$\text{var}\left[ e^\top \Sigma^{-1} \left( e \theta + u \right) \right] = \sigma_0^2 e^\top \Sigma^{-1} e e^\top \Sigma^{-1} e + e^\top \Sigma^{-1} e$$
